# Button on click bug in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.forms version `3.0.0.561731` for the Application.The issue is, when a button is clicked another button like object at top left corner is appearing for few seconds which is very annoying, I have been searching for couple of hours and tried what ever stuff found but no luck.

I tried upgrading to latest xamarin.forms version and also tried to downgrading it upto 2.4.0 but still the issue exists.

Please guide me to get rid of that visual effect issue while tapping/clicking on button.

```
 <Button BorderRadius="5" Text="Continue" HorizontalOptions='FillAndExpand' BackgroundColor="#1976D2" TextColor="White" Command="{Binding ContinueFormCommand}">
        <Button.FontSize>
           <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
               <OnIdiom.Phone>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="13" Android="15" WinPhone="30"/>
                </OnIdiom.Phone>
                <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="13" Android="15" WinPhone="30"/>
                </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                  </OnIdiom>
           </Button.FontSize>
               <Button.HeightRequest>
                  <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                   <OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="13" Android="45" WinPhone="30"/>
                    </OnIdiom.Phone>
                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="13" Android="15" WinPhone="30"/>
                    </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                  </OnIdiom>
             </Button.HeightRequest>
        </Button>
```

[image]
I got this issue for Samsung device.

Comment: do you implement any code? if you share your code

Comment: Thanks for response @RahulChokshi, I have updated the code for button which I implemented.

Comment: is it possible share screenshot what exactly happen in an application

Comment: @RahulChokshi, updated screenshort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is open for way too long on GitHub [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3220) and [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2096).

As a work around, you can using Xamarin.Forms v2.5.0.122203 which doesn't have the issue.